# Why adding a CodeIgniter constructor producing error 500

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello everyone 
I have a site controller code as below..... when I try to execute this code I get a weird problem, If I take out the __construct() function everything works pretty well for me, but, as soon as I add that constructor function I get the error 500 internal server error can any one help me out ??

```
<?php

class site extends CI_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
       parent::CI_Controller();
       $this->Logged_in();
    }


    function after_logging()
    {
        $this->load->view('home');
    }

    function Logged_in()
    {
        $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
        if(!isset($is_logged_in)|| $is_logged_in != TRUE)
        {
            die();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: did you try to use `parent::__construct()` instead of `parent::CI_Controller()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this CI 2.0?

In that case, use this for the constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
        // your code
}
```

Comment: Looks like he's indeed on version 2, where Controller is renamed CI_Controller. @koool: User guide reference here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#constructors